# HTML5 video player with controls + play on hover

Tags: css, html, html5-video

I would like to use Bootstrap + HTML5 video player on my website. Here is what I've got:

```
<div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <div class="instruction">
    <p>
    click play to launch fullscreen. click replay to watch in the container from the beginning.
    </p>
    <button href="#" id="play">
    Play
    </button>
    <button href="#" id="replay">
    Replay
    </button>
    </div>
    <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
        <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
    </video>
</div>

.instruction {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:99;
  color:#fff;
  top:50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pw7yzLfg/1/

WHat I would like to achieve:

- Video should fill entire container (100% width + auto height),
- By default it should be stopped; play only on hover
- I would like to use simple controls: play (after clicking watch video fullscreen) and replay (play from the beginning in the container).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on it for some time now. This is the result.

I have used JS event handlers, video element attributes and methods along with percentage size specification for CSS elements.

*Note that launching full-screen on pressing a custom button is currently not supported.*

```js
var video=document.getElementById('robot_video')
   
function play(event){
 video.play();
}

function replay(event){
 video.currentTime=0;
}
```

```css
html,body{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

html,body,#video_container{
 width:100%;
 height: 100%;
}

video{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.instruction{
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 text-align: center;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:99;
 color:#fff;
 bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Video</title> 
 </head>
 <body>
  <div align="center" id="video_container" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
   <div class="instruction">
    <p>
     click play to launch fullscreen. click replay to watch in the container from the beginning.
    </p>
    <button href="#" id="play" onclick="play(event);">
     Play
    </button>
    <button href="#" id="replay" onclick="replay(event);">
     Replay
    </button>
   </div>
   <video controls id="robot_video" class="embed-responsive-item" onmouseover="play(event);">
    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
   </video>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```